# how to show changes to items in gitignore

Tags: git

I was wondering how to show changes made to the items in .gitignore.  So say, I have a file `foo.txt` which is included in `.gitignore`, but I'd like to still see if `foo.txt` has been added to my local repo though not committed to it. How would I be able to see this?

Comment: How could it be added to the repo if it's in the .gitignore? Even if you can, it'll show up the same as any other file.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status
```

If `new:  foo.txt` appears in the sector of `Changes to be committed`, then it's been added but not committed. If it's `modified:  foo.txt`, it's already been tracked but the new version has not been committed yet. If it does not show in `git status` but shows in `git status --ignored`, it's ignored and not added yet.

```
git show HEAD:foo.txt
```

If it prints the content of the file, `foo.txt` has been tracked. If it prints `fatal: Path 'foo.txt' exists on disk, but not in 'HEAD'.`, it's not tracked in the current commit.

```
git check-ignore -v foo.txt
```

If it prints the ignore file in which `foo.txt` is ignored, it's not added or committed yet.